# Design testing for form-intensive web application

Tags: javascript, testing

I'm designing a web application which can display an arbitrary series of forms to users (surveys, essentially). It's an all-one-page style application, so all the scripting is in javascript. I want to be able to test a given set of forms by automatically scraping fields like `<select>` and `<input type="radio">` for potential values and randomly choosing one, without knowing what valid values would be in advance. Are there any useful scripts to do this?

More precisely, given an (unknown in advance, arbitrary, containing any kind of field) form:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="1">
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="2">
  <select name="mySelect">
    <option value="a">
    <option value="b">
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="myText">
</form>
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
possibilities = scanForm('myForm');
```

and get this:

```
{
    myRadio: ["1", "2"],
    mySelect: ["a", "b"],
    myText: []
}
```

I know I could write this all myself, but taking care of all the edge cases (`<select multiple>`?) and browser testing it would be a pain, and unnecessary if this already exists somewhere.

Note also that things like Selenium or iMacros aren't useful because this is entirely client-side and programmatic. GUI's, browser plug-ins, and server-side languages won't work.

I would also welcome comments on whether or not this idea is somehow misconceived.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like..

```
var inputs = document.getElementById('myForm').getElementsByTagName('input');
var myText = Array();

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].type == "text") {
        myText.push(inputs[i].value);
    } else if (inputs[i].type == "radio") [
        // push inputs[i].value onto your myRadio array
    } else {
        // other cases
    }
}
// handle selects.. textareas
```